# What is $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\tan{x}}{\sec{x}} $

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

What is

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\tan{x}}{\sec{x}} $$

Can I substitute $\tan(x)$ with $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ ? Or $\tan(\infty)$ has a value ?

Comment: I have edited your question to include LaTeX. Please make sure it is correct.

Comment: Of course you can. $\frac{\tan(x)}{\sec(x)}=\frac{(\sin(x)/ \cos(x))}{(1/ \cos(x))}=\sin(x)$, but as you can see, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Technically, $\tan(x)/\sec(x)$ is undefined for certain arbitrarily large values of $x$, so the limit as $x\to \infty$ can't exist.  The same would be true for $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sec(x)/\sec(x)$, although in many contexts it would be reasonable to simplify that to $1$.

Comment: @ErickWong Perhaps that is a definitional issue. The notation $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ means that for every positive $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that for all $x>\delta$ , $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. The question is, do we consider $x \in \text{dom(f)}$ or $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 - A fair point, but one can't simply restrict to the domain of $f$ or else the limit can take any value for points outside the closure of the domain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\tan{x}}{\sec{x}}$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \tan{x}\cos{x}$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\cos{x}$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin{x}$ which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x...\text{doesn't exist .}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, simplify the expression to 
$$\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}{\frac{1}{\cos x}} = \sin x.$$
The result then is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You are correct. Substitute $\tan{x}$ with $\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}$ and you'll find the answer very easily.